# How do I implement SearchView with no errors

Tags: java, android, listview

I am a beginner and new to coding. I have a problem with ListView in Android Studio. I have created a simple activity with a simple Listview. The Listview contains locations, and when the user clicks on an item the app will open google maps and takes the user to that location. The problem occurred when I implemented a SearchView. When search is applied, whatever result is filtered it will always open the first location. So could you please help me with that. Thanks.
This is my code and sorry for the mess.

```
MainActivity.java

import com.example.myapplicationsecond.R;

public class MainActivity9 extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView listView;
    String[] name = {"First Location","Second Location","Third Location","Fourth Location",};

    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main9);

        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.abs_layout, null);
        ActionBar.LayoutParams params = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(
                ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                Gravity.CENTER);

        TextView Title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.actionbar_title);
        Title.setText("Search Here");

        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(view,params);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true); //show custom title
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false); //hide the default title


        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Search Here");


        listView = findViewById(R.id.listview);

        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,name);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);


        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if(position==0){

                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW , Uri.parse("geo: 21.422458, 39.826213"));
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
                if(position==1){

                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW , Uri.parse("geo: 24.467275, 39.610629"));
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
                if(position==2){

                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW , Uri.parse("geo: 25.173059, 45.142079"));
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
                if(position==3){

                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW , Uri.parse("geo: 26.348400, 43.766664"));
                    startActivity(intent);


            }

            }

        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {


        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu,menu);


        MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menuItem.getActionView();
        searchView.setQueryHint("Search Here");

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {


                arrayAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);



                return false;
            }
        });

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }




}


MainActivity.Xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity9">


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:textDirection="locale"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

thats how you coded it, you have `if(position==0)` so no matter what will be on first position you will open same `geo:`. you should check WHAT is on first position when clicked, so inside `onItemClick` put:

```
String clickedText = arrayAdapter.getItem(position);
```

then find position of this item in all-items array

```
int positionInArray = java.util.Arrays.asList(name).indexOf(clickedText);
```

and now use `positionInArray` for your `is` `else`

but thats a quick fix, you should have some model, your custom class with two variables, `String name` and `String geoUri` or two `long`s for lat and lng

Comment: I am extremely thankful for you r fast response. Unfortunately, I am a beginner and couldn't apply your code. Could you please specify what to put and where to put it please. Thanks a lot.